# How to limit a process to use X memory and T time?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I think one solution to this problem is **ulimit** . But I found following code in domjudge, how they are handling this can somebody explain.They are not using ulimit.I am not good at shell.But still your little help can clear my doubt.

```
# Runs command without error trapping and check exitcode
runcheck ()
{
set +e
$@
exitcode=$?
set -e
}

runcheck $GAINROOT $RUNGUARD ${DEBUG:+-v} ${USE_CHROOT:+-r "$PWD"} -u "$RUNUSER" \
-t $TIMELIMIT -m $MEMLIMIT -f $FILELIMIT -p $PROCLIMIT -c -o program.time -- \
$PREFIX/run $PREFIX/$PROGRAM \
testdata.in program.out program.err program.exit \
>error.tmp 2>&1
```

Run Script:

```
PROGRAM="$1";   shift
TESTIN="$1";    shift
OUTPUT="$1";    shift
ERROR="$1";     shift
EXITFILE="$1";  shift
```

**Run the program while redirecting input, output and stderr**

```
$PROGRAM <$TESTIN >$OUTPUT 2>$ERROR
exitcode=$?

printf "$exitcode" >$EXITFILE

exit $exitcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Ulimit works from the shell (which actually calls the `ulimit` system call).

In DOMjudge the restrictions are set using the program `runguard`. If you want to know more details, see the source code, or ask on the [DOMjudge mailinglist](http://www.domjudge.org/mailman/listinfo/domjudge-devel)